# Why can't I open MS Office files in the web browser?

Tags: browser, ms-office

I'm trying to open multiple MS Office files (like Excel, PowerPoint & Word) in my web browser.

It works fine when i'm using MS Office 2003 in one PC, but when I try to run the same application in another PC having MS Office 2007, then instead of showing the MS Office file in the web browser, it opens the file in MS Office.

Does anyone know the solution to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is by design, Office [2007 intentionally removed the browser flag registry entries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927009) to discourage this behavior because it does not work that well when being hosted. And dsoframer is pulled from KB also. Prepare to migrate your office automation code to a plugin, probably using VSTO.